# parse() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, nltk

When running this code :

```
import nltk
parser = nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser(working_dir="c:\maltparser-1.7.2",mco="engmalt.linear-   1.7", additional_java_args=['-Xmx512m'])
tree=parser.raw_parse("Hi,I am Kruthika");
```

I am getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
   tree=parser.raw_parse("Hi,I am Kruthika");
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0a3-py2.7.egg\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 127, in raw_parse
return self.parse(words, verbose)
TypeError: parse() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I have given only one argument
I am trying to use MaltParser in Python (Windows OS)..

Comment: Why do you say it's just one argument?! I see these: 1. `working_dir="c:\maltparser-1.7.2"` 2. `mco="engmalt.linear-   1.7"` and 3. `additional_java_args=['-Xmx512m']`

Comment: 1 for parser.raw_parse ..I have 3 for  nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser

Comment: You only gave one argument (other than the implicit `self`) to `raw_parse()`, but it called `parse()` with three: `self` (implicit in any method invocation), `words` and `verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try upgrading to the latest version (3.0a4) of NLTK. From your path ("C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0a3-py2.7.egg\nltk\parse\malt.py"), you seem to have 3.0a3.

The issue is in `raw_parse`. The last line of the function calls `self.parse`

```
def raw_parse(self, sentence, verbose=False):
    """
    Use MaltParser to parse a sentence. Takes a sentence as a string;
    before parsing, it will be automatically tokenized and tagged with this
    MaltParser instance's tagger.

    :param sentence: Input sentence to parse
    :type sentence: str
    :return: ``DependencyGraph`` the dependency graph representation of the sentence
    """
    words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    return self.parse(words, verbose)
```

And the signature in the current version is `MaltParser.parse(self, words, verbose=False)`, which should indeed take 3 arguments ("self" is passed automatically), but in your case it's complaining that parse takes only 2 arguments.

You can have a look at `help(parser.parse)` to see what the signature is in the version that you have, but it's probably a bug.